# Physical interfaces bound using igb_uio not coming up on "show port info all" in dpdk-testpmd

Tags: dpdk, mknod

Repro steps:

1. Bind physical interfaces to igb_uio using dpdk-devbind.
2. Run dpdk-testpmd with log-level set to debug, we will see "EAL: Cannot open /dev/uio0: No such file or directory".
3. Do ls -l /dev | grep uio and nothing comes up.

What to do?

Expectation is that after binding physical interfaces to igb_uio using dpdk-devbind, u should see the interface in the "show port info all" when u run dpdk-testpmd.

Comment: please add detailed steps.. like what are the configuration of your server like OS, NIC etc,. Then say which command you executed and what were the outcome.